# why angularstrap modal blink when i try to close it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am using **angularjs** version 1.4.4 and **angularstrap** version 2.3.7 and as is mentioned in angularstrap documentation I am using angularmotion witch is accessible in its [github][1]. but when I am using modal when close modal it will blink after closing.

Comment: In angular 1.4.4 animation was broken, You should either try upgrading your angular files to latest version? or you should disable animation while opening popup..there must be option such as `animation: false`

Comment: i upgrade angular it to 1.4.8 but problem not resolve

Comment: did you updated other angular related files, such as `angular-animate`, `angular-sanitize`, etc.?

Comment: yes i replace all file in angular folder

Comment: did you tried making `animation: false` in modal settings?

Comment: no i want use animation in first step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution and that was this :

1. set **backdrop animation** to **false**.
2. and change animation property from **am-fade** to **am-fade-and-slide-top**.

and the problem resolved.